# Why is the caulk cracking and the toilet rocking?

Tags: bathroom, shower, caulking

We paid a lot of money to have our bathroom gutted and redone.  After several problems with the contractor not returning calls to correct shoddy work, we are at a loss.  I am not sure if the shower was tiled properly (or the toilet seated correctly for that matter—it rocks all the time).  The caulking has come apart so many times already.  The soap dish fell off the wall.  The towel bar was recaulked, along with the base of the tub, where the tile meets. Every couple of months, it pulls apart or cracks open.  Why is this happening?  We do have a fan, and the contractor checked it, it is venting, so don't think it's a moisture issue.

Answer (score 12):

You don't have a caulking problem, you have a structural one. The walls and floor shouldn't be moving so much that caulk cracks. And caulk isn't an adhesive for holding up the soap dish or towel bar. Finally, a rocking toilet indicates the floor either wasn't properly leveled or that it's not structurally sound. If these are the issues you are noticing, then you can be sure that there are a lot more serious problems you aren't seeing.

You don't want that contractor back in your house to fix these problems. You want to sue them for gross negligence and to get someone that knows what they are doing to come in and fix it. To fix it right likely requires gutting your bathroom all over again and starting over from scratch.